# Add next button to right of UINavigationBar?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I was wondering how would one add an up and down arrow to the right of a UINavigationBar for a tableview detail view. I want to create something similar to the buttons in mail: clicking one to go up and one to go down.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try an UIFlexibleSpace, followed by two buttons.